# If masses are stuck on a rod, how it's moment of inertia changes?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, reference-frames, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

Supposedly I keep a rod of mass 3 kg and length 2 meters on a smooth desk, such that masses of 1 kg and 2 kg are stuck firmly to top and bottom of the rod respectively.

Now, the center of mass of the resultant body is changed, from what I've calculated, it has shifted 1/6 meters below the center of the rod.

Now, if I rotate the rod, and I'm interested in calculating its moment of inertia (resultant), then-

Do I've to keep considering the center of the rod as the reference point, i.e., axis of rotation, or, I've to shift the axis of rotation to the center of mass, i.e., 1/6 meters below the center?

I've calculated both the results, and need some confirmation on this.

Comment: I want to clarify, I've done almost the calculations, and need some insight on it, even without calculations, therefor its not specifically homework and exercises category.

Comment: The moment of inertia is different depending on which axis of rotation you choose.

Comment: suppose the two masses hit the rod at rest, each in opposite direction, such as to produce a net torque, then to calculate the angular momentum I need to find the moment of inertia. now this moment of inertia should be about the centre of the rod or the centre of the mass which is shifted?

Comment: If the rod is free to move it will rotate about its new centre of mass.

Comment: can you please calculate & share your moment of inertia?

Comment: Don't you trust your own ability to do this simple calculation?. ... Choose any point as reference - eg one end A where a mass is. Then the total moment of the 2 remaining masses about A equals the moment of all 3 masses if placed at the new COM. This gives you the distance of the new COM from end A. .... Note that you must conserve linear momentum also as well as angular momentum.

Comment: You can discuss your problems and solutions more freely in the chatroom [Problem Solving Strategies](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54160/problem-solving-strategies). John Rennie is usually there every day for several hours.

Comment: Actually, as I said (or not), this is just a key part of a much different question. I am still discussing it with some of my friends. After all, the moment of interia needs to be fitted in an equation ahead, and solved further. However, thanks for your suggestion.